# Use requests module in Python to log in to Barclays premier league fantasy football?

Tags: python, session, authentication, request

I'm trying to write a Python script to let me log in to my fantasy football account at https://fantasy.premierleague.com/, but something is not quite right with my log in. When I login through my browser and check the details using Chrome developer tools, I find that the Request URL is https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/ and the form data sent is:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken:[My token]
login:[My username]
password:[My password]
app:plfpl-web
redirect_uri:https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/login
```

There are also a number of Request headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:185
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:[My cookies]
Host:users.premierleague.com
Origin:https://fantasy.premierleague.com
Referer:https://fantasy.premierleague.com/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
```

So I've written a short Python script using the request library to try to log in and navigate to a page as follows:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as session:
url_home = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/'
html_home = session.get(url_home)
csrftoken = session.cookies['csrftoken']
values = {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
    'login': <My username>,
    'password': <My password>,
    'app': 'plfpl-web',
    'redirect_uri': 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/login'
}
head = {
    'Host':'users.premierleague.com',
    'Referer': 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/',
}
session.post('https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/', 
             data = values, headers = head)
url_transfers = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/squad/transfers'
html_transfers = session.get(url_transfers)
print(html_transfers.content)
```

On printing out the content of my post request, I get a HTML response code 500 error with:

```
b'\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Fastly error: unknown domain users.premierleague.com</title>\n</head>\n<body>\nFastly error: unknown domain: users.premierleague.com. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.</body></html>'
```

If I remove the 'host' from my head dict, I get a HTML response code 405 error with:

```
b''
```

I've tried including various combinations of the Request headers in my head dict and nothing seems to work.

Comment: What happened when you use  `premierleague.com` as a `Host` ?

Comment: @OrDuan I get the same message: unknown domain premierleague.com

Comment: Hi. Do you know how to update squads etc or initiate transfers using python?

Comment: @EkanshGupta I'm afraid not, I just wanted to scrape data. I assume you will need to figure out the correct post request. If you use google chrome, you can do a transfer in your browser and follow what happens using the developer tools. It should tell you want information is being sent and retrieved. There are similar tools in other browsers to do the same thing. Sorry I can't help more. Good luck.

Comment: It's ok. I figured that out. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me. I simply removed `headers = head`

```
session.post('https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/', 
             data = values)
```

I think you are trying to pick your team programmatically, like me. Your code got me started thanks.

Comment: thanks, that does seem to work. I did actually try that before, but the HTML it sent back didn't contain any player names in it, so I assumed it was just feeding back the home page to me! It seems the players data aren't coded in the HTML, but maybe printed by javascript? I downloaded the source code in google chrome and nothing shows. Do you know how to get the full HTML so that you can parse it and make player changes?